# need help creating a comment section in MVC app

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post

Need to add a comment section to my code for a detais pane.

Hi All,

I am creating as a test project an application to manage and help with IT tickets. I have a details pane which displays a post form allowing me to view details and update any if necessary. All is working well except that I need to create a comment section to add details on work that has been already completed in the details pane.

```
@model TicketingSystem.ViewModels.TicketFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Tickets"))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Subject)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Subject, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Subject)


    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.SenderName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.SenderName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.SenderName)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.SenderEmail)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.SenderEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.SenderEmail)
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Message)
        <br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(t => t.Message)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.StateId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(t => t.StateId, new SelectList(Model.State, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.StateId)
    </div>


    @Html.HiddenFor(t=>t.Id , new { @class = "form-control"})

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

I was hoping to get a small chat box-like feature that will have a small text box with a "post" button under which would allow me to submit to my comments model. I am really not sure how to even start implementing something like that. Any pointers would be majorly appreciated as I am fairly new to the MVC and web apps as a whole.

Comment: Depending on how you're populating the 'details' page you can either add a List<T> of comments to the current view model and pass those in on the details controller OR you can load them via AJAX (just depends on how lengthy these might by and if you need paging, etc.). Either way, the 'comment' submission will be a second form entirely either posting with a new using() tag helper or handling the submission through Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Comments model (if you're using EF) that would have an association to this TicketView model (whatever pk your ticket model has).  Then within your view, I'd create a _Comments partial which has a TextArea and a Submit button.  In fact, I've done this very thing and it works.  The submit button in the _Comments partial would post the comment and return back to the view with the comment in it.

My Model is set up like this.  I have a one-to-many relationship between requests and responses.  Responses have groups.  Within each group of responses I have one or more GroupComment(s).

For example, in my parent view (which has a ViewModel of responses, groups and group comments)...

```
   <section class="comments">
        <label class="commentsLabel">Comments:</label>
        <span> 
           @Html.Partial("_CommentsPartial", comment)               
        </span>                                                          
    </section>
```

Then my comments partial looks like this (What this does is show the comments if any exist.  If no comments exist yet, I have an Add button so the user can add a comment:

```
@model IEnumerable<GroupComment>
@{
   var comment = Model;    
   foreach (var c in comment)
   {
       if (c.COMMENT_ID > 0)
       {
      <div>
       <img src="~/Content/note.jpg" /><span 
        class="comment">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Comments", new { id = 
      c.COMMENT_ID }, null)</span> @c.COMMENTS
     </div>
        } else {
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add \u00BB", "Create", "Comments", new { NCR_REQUEST_ID = c.NCR_REQUEST_ID, NCR_GROUPS_ID = c.NCR_GROUPS_ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
        </div>
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I was also entertaining the idea of doing it through jquery and ajax but I am leaning on these methods. I will update you on how it goes.